# Converting Outlook Express 64-bit into Outlook Express 32-bit

Tags: email, 64-bit, 32-bit, outlook-express

It appears that Outlook Express on Windows XP 64-bit uses a different format of DBX files than the 32-bit version. Is there a way to convert 64-bit store folder DBX into a version that the 32-bit version will be able to read? I tried to import from store folder in the 32-bit version, but it doesn't seem to even recognize the DBX files inside.

It is very odd that the same program uses different storage formats, but it seems that this is just the case.

So are there any methods to move messages out of 64-bit Outlook Express 6?

Comment: You tried to move .dbx files to same path on 32bit xp, right? Alternatively you may drag'n'drop all messages from/to outlook (express) via .eml files.

Comment: @week Dragging through eml files is just too tedious and additionally I will lose flags and some email files may have same file name due to same subject. It is not for moving thousands of emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some examination I found no way to convert store folder format except using third party programs and importing into Windows Mail or Windows Live Mail which doesn't really convert the messages but it moves them. So my conclusion is that it cannot be converted.